# How can I create and alter a new string[][] without altering the original?

Tags: c#

I know this is an issue being caused by passing by reference rather than value, but I'm not sure what I need to do to fix it.

I have a field variable `string[][] _cubeState` which represents the state of a 2x2 Rubiks cube. This jagged array represents the state of the cube before any rotations take place and should be updated after every rotation, but only after my rotate method has returned and overwritten it.

What is actually happening is that when I get to the `newCube[0][index] = _cubeState[0][index + 10];` line, this line updates both my `newCube` array and my original `_cubeState` array. Since the newCube is referencing cubeState it's also updating the original. How do I fix this so that the cubeState will only update after the method has returned?

```
private string[][] _cubeState;

public Rubiks () {
    _cubeState = new string[][] {
        new [] { "A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "C", "D", "D", "E", "E", "F", "F" },
        new [] { "A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "C", "D", "D", "E", "E", "F", "F" }
    };

    _cubeState = RotateAcw (0);
}

public string[][] RotateAcw (int index) {
    string[][] newCube = { _cubeState[0], _cubeState[1] };

    newCube[0][index] = _cubeState[0][index + 10];
    newCube[1][index] = _cubeState[1][index + 10];

    return newCube;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't copy a jagged array like this:

```
string[][] newCube = { _cubeState[0], _cubeState[1] };
```

You are not actually copying the inner arrays.

To copy the inner arrays, you can use [`Array.Copy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.copy?view=netframework-4.8#System_Array_Copy_System_Array_System_Array_System_Int32_). One way to do this is this:

```
var newCubeState = new string[_cubeState.Length][];
for (int i = 0 ; i < _cubeState.Length ; i++) {
    string[] inner = new string[_cubeState[i].Length];
    Array.Copy(_cubeState[i], inner, _cubeState[i].Length);
    newCubeState[i] = inner;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is how to copy the jagged array:

```
string[][] cubeState = new string[][] {
    new [] { "A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "C", "D", "D", "E", "E", "F", "F" },
    new [] { "A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "C", "D", "D", "E", "E", "F", "F" }
};

string[][] newCube = cubeState.Select(x => x.ToArray()).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

A bit shorter and slower alternative with `Array.Clone` :

```
string[][] newCube = Array.ConvertAll(_cubeState, x => x.Clone());
```